# SoapUI - Load test properties in a file from the command line

Tags: soapui

As described in the documentation at http://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-from-command-line/load-tests.html it is possible to run SoapUI from the command line and pass in properties using the `P` flag as a series of name/value pairs.

I have a large number of properties to pass in - is it possible to load these from a single file rather than as multiple flags passed to the `loadtestrunner` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/working-with-properties.html#2-Setting-properties-from-the-command-line):

> An extended possibility to override/set properties at the project/testsuite/testcase/mockservice level is also available by adding a
>   `soapui.properties.=pathtopropertiesfile`
>   value to the global or system properties, where shortened-name-of-object is the name of the corresponding object with only characters. For example if you have a TestSuite in your project named "TestSuite 1", you can set
>   `-Dsoapui.properties.TestSuite1=testsuite1props.properties`
>   which will load the properties in the specified file ("testsuite1props.properties") into the "TestSuite 1" TestSuite properties (please note that any TestSuite names "TestSuite 1" in any of your projects will be affected).

Comment: I've been looking for that feature using maven-soap-plugin but seems I just can specify a list of properties but no reference to a file in the pom.xml. Anyone knows how to do that? https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

Comment: @exoddus, that should be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note [SiKing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33131613/2828611).

You can do the same from the pom.xml by adding the following configuration to the **`soapui-maven-plugin`**:

```
      <configuration>
        <soapuiProperties combine.children="append">
          <property>
            <name>soapui.properties.TestSuite1</name>
            <value>testsuite1props.properties</value>
          </property>
        </soapuiProperties>
      </configuration>
```

I did not test it for TestSuite imports, but the global ones work:

```
      <configuration>
        <soapuiProperties combine.children="append">
          <property>
            <name>soapui.properties</name>
            <value>global.properties</value>
          </property>
        </soapuiProperties>
      </configuration>
```

According to some posts it should also work for project properties:

```
      <configuration>
        <soapuiProperties combine.children="append">
          <property>
            <name>soapui.properties.Project1</name>
            <value>Project1props.properties</value>
          </property>
        </soapuiProperties>
      </configuration>
```

Comment: If you want a super dynamic setting you can also pass and concat command line properties. `${SoapuiEnvironment}` in your pom.xml would be replaced by the value you pass into `-DSoapuiEnvironment=integration`.

Comment: Don't know why it doesn't work
`<soapuiProperties combine.children="append">
        <property>
         <name>soapui.properties</name>
         <value>${project.basedir}/src/resources/properties/env-qa.properties</value>
        </property>
       </soapuiProperties> `